# JqueryUI Sortable load use order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Side Menu which I want the user to sort the menu items in his own preference.
How can I, on page load in a user session, load the user's custom order from the DB sending the info with json from my php.
Suppose I have saved the user's order in the DB using the .toArray or .serialize method of .sortable
like this

```
$("#sidr-id-mainList").sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        result = $("#sidr-id-mainList").sortable("toArray");
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.com/API/menu/list/save",
            type: "POST",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Result: result
            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("XMLHttpRequest=" + XMLHttpRequest + "; textStatus=" + textStatus + "; errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
var custumOrder = ["item4", "item2", "item1", "item3"];

var ul = $("#sortable");
var items = $("#sortable li");

for (item of custumOrder) {
    ul.append($('#' + item + ''));
}

$("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        alert(order);
    }
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/zyawjzL5/)